# Failed to start apache22

Tags: freebsd, httpd.conf, apache2.2

My knowledge is at a very basic level.
But I have special task for running Apache.

**FreeBSD 8.1**

At first, when I tried to perform command:

```
#apachectl start
```

was an error:

```
[warn](2) No such file or directory: Failed to enable the 'httpready' AcceptFilter
[warn](2) No such file or directory: Failed to enable the 'dataready' AcceptFilter
```

Then I added to the file /boot/loader.conf :

```
accf_http_load="YES"
accf_data_load="YES"
```

And when I perform

```
#/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22 start
```

I get this:

```
Performing sanity check on apache22 configuration:
Syntax OK
Starting apache22.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22: WARNING: failed to start apache22
```

Command:

```
#apachectl start
```

returns without any errors

In httpd-error.log I can see only this:

```
(21)Is a directory: httpd: could not open error log file /home/httpd-logs/hostname.example.error.log.
Unable to open logs
```

So the question is: How to start apache22 ?

Comment: Just in case `nginx` + `FreeBSD` work pretty well, maybe worth to give a try

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
The reason was in bad extension of error log files that was written in `httpd.conf` for VirtualHost

That's why I saw message

```
(21)Is a directory: httpd: could not open error log file /home/httpd-logs/hostname.example.error.log.
Unable to open logs
```

in `/var/log/httpd-error.log`

So i just create new log files in `/home/httpd-logs/` where they were all recorded